# Scanner error using java

Tags: java

When I try to compile it shows these two errors...whats the problem?

### 1 error and 1 warning found:

### *** Error ***

File: C:\Users\User\Desktop\J Sargeant Reynolds\csc201\week 7\GreetingLab.java  [line: 23]

### Error: in cannot be resolved

### ** Warning **

File: C:\Users\User\Desktop\J Sargeant Reynolds\csc201\week 7\GreetingLab.java  [line: 9]
Warning: Resource leak: 'in' is never closed

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GreetingLab {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException    {
      String title;
      String firstName;
      String lastName;
      Scanner in;
      in = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter a title:");
      title = in.next();
      System.out.print("Enter your first name:");
      firstName = in.next();
      System.out.print("Enter a your last name:");
      lastName = in.next();
      greeting(title,firstName,lastName);
      }
      private static void greeting (String ttl, String fName, String lName)
      { 
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println ("Dear "+ttl+" "+fName+" "+lName+",");
          System.out.println();
          in.close();
      }
 }
```

Comment: You don't need to put the error in **bold**. Improve the formatting of the code.

Answer (score 0):

The in variable is declared inside of your main method, but called from greeting.  greeting has no access to in.

I would probably move all the Scanner creation code into the greeting function.

Answer (score 0):

Scanner in is only visible in your main Method scope, so you cant close it in another method.
Try closing the Scanner in your main, after greeting(...); e.g.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurred because it cannot recognize `in` which is not within the scope of your greeting method.

There are at least **2 simply ways** you can do to let greeting method be able to access `in`.

1. Declare `in` as a class variable

   ```
   public class GreetingLab {
       static Scanner in;    // <-----Create your in here (outside your main)
       public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException    {
   ```
2. Declare in within greeting method.

   ```
   private static void greeting (String ttl, String fName, String lName)
   { 
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in) //<----Create in within method
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
1)public class GreetingLab {

private static Scanner in;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException    {
  String title;
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  in = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Enter a title:");
  title = in.next();
  System.out.print("Enter your first name:");
  firstName = in.next();
  System.out.print("Enter a your last name:");
  lastName = in.next();
  greeting(title,firstName,lastName);
  }
  private static void greeting (String ttl, String fName, String lName)
  { 
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println ("Dear "+ttl+" "+fName+" "+lName+",");
      System.out.println();
      in.close();
  }
```

}

The error comes cause the **Scanner in** was not visible **to the method  greeting**.

2)Also if you dont want to take the Variable Scanner out of the main method you can pass it to Method greeting like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){//main Method
   .....
 greeting(title,firstName,lastName,in );
}

private static void greeting (String ttl, String fName, String   lName,Scanner in){
 ..
}
```